# Can't pass variables to function with Tkinter in python

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to take the textvariable from an entry(a) and then put it in a label in a new window(w).

```
from Tkinter import *
def abind(avar):
    print avar
    w=Toplevel()
    at=Label(w, text=avar).pack()
    w.mainloop()
app=Tk()
at=StringVar()
a=Entry(app,textvariable=at)
avar=at.get()
a.pack()
a.focus()
b=Button(app, command=abind(avar)).pack()
app.mainloop()
```

It either prints blank, if I take the avar out of the parantheses after abind, or opens a new window immeadiatley and doesn't display the button widget, if I leave the avar.

Comment: Try `avar = a.get()`

Answer (score 1):

There are two main problems with your code:

- with `avar=at.get()`, the `avar` variable has the value of the text variable *at that point in time*, i.e. it is just the empty string
- with `Button(app, command=abind(avar))`, you are *calling* the function `abind(avar)` and using its *result* as a command, i.e. `None`

Also, by doing `b=Button(...).pack()`, `b` is the result of `pack()`, i.e. `None`. This is not related to your problem, but it's probably not what you intended, either. Try this:

```
b = Button(app, command=lambda: abind(at.get()))
b.pack()
```

This uses `lambda` to create a new anonymous function that will get the current value from `at` using `at.get()` and call `abind` with that value, setting the text of the `Label` accordingly.

If you want the `Label` to be updated as you type additional text into the `Entry`, try this:

```
def abind(avar):
    ...
    at = Label(w, textvariable=avar)  # use textvariable
    at.pack                           # pack again
    ...
...
b = Button(app, command=lambda: abind(at)) # pass at itself
...
```